# Generate points of a (n-2)-sphere on a n-hyperplane

Tags: pr.probability, geometry

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Efficiently sampling points uniformly from the surface of an n-sphere](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/24688/efficiently-sampling-points-uniformly-from-the-surface-of-an-n-sphere)

I'm trying to generate random points of a (n-2)-sphere on a n-hyperplane so basically the intersection of a (n-1)-sphere and a n-hyperplane.

The hyperplane here is the plane associated with a (n-1)-simplex of equation: $x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_n = 1$

I know the radius $R$ of the n-sphere and I know the center $a$ which is in the simplex.
$a = (a_1, a_2, ..., a_n)$ and $a_1+a_2+...+a_3=1$

So the points I want to generate are solution of :

$x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_n = 1$ and 
$(x_1-a_1)^2 + (x_2-a_2)^2 + ... + (x_n-a_n)^2 = R^2$

I absolutely need to generate points uniformly and in Cartesian coordinates.

I have been looking into it for a few days now and cannot seem to find a good way to do it.

For the moment I did it on $\mathbb{R}^3$ which is equivalent to generate points of a circle on a plane. To do so, I projected the space on the 2-simplex (3D->2D) and I generated points of a circle using :

$(u,v) = \frac{R}{\sqrt{X_1^2 + X_2^2}}(X_1,X_2)$ where $X_1, X_2$ are independent gaussians.

(this algorithm allows you to generate points on a n-sphere too)

Finally, I used an "inverse-projection" of the simplex to the space (after some calculus...) :

$z = \sqrt{2/3} \cdot v $

$y = \frac{u}{\sqrt{2}} - 1/2 \cdot z$

$x=1-y-z$

Here is a graph to give you an exemple of what I just presented in 3 dimensions. The standard 2-simplex is the area represented in cyan.

http://www.freeimagehosting.net/t/aksf6.jpg
(sorry cannot post image tags...)

Of course, those formulas are easily derived in 3 dimensions but not as easily in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

I feel like I am looking at the problem the wrong way so any idea is welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: when you say uniformly, you mean uniformly with respect to the $(n-2)$-dimensional Lebesgue measure living on the intersection of the hyperplane and the sphere?

Comment: That's the idea (e.g uniformity of  the points generated on the circle in $\mathbb{R}^3$)

Comment: The problem of rotating and translating points on a sphere is outside the scope of this forum.  You may want to ask at one of the other websites listed in the FAQ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll answer using matrix vector notation, which generalizes the problem to multiple linear constraints. We wish to generate a point $\mathbf{x}$ which is in the intersection of a hypersphere and an affine space, which we can write like this:

$$\|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_0\|=r$$
$$\mathbf{Ax}=\mathbf{b}$$

Then we can generate $\mathbf{x}$ with this procedure:

$$\mathbf{z} \sim \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{0},\mathbf{I}) $$
$$\mathbf{z} := \mathbf{z} - \mathbf{A}^\dagger\mathbf{Az}$$
$$\mathbf{y} := \mathbf{A}^\dagger (\mathbf{b}-\mathbf{Ax}_0)$$
$$\mathbf{x} := \mathbf{x}_0 + \mathbf{y} + \frac{\mathbf{z}}{\|\mathbf{z}\|}(r - \|\mathbf{y}\|)$$

The idea here is that the point $\mathbf{x}_0 + \mathbf{y}$ is the center of the intersection, and $\mathbf{z}/\|\mathbf{z}\|$ is uniformly distributed on the unit sphere of the null space of $\mathbf{A}$.

Note, we must have $r \ge \|\mathbf{y}\|$, otherwise the intersection is empty. Also, we assume $\mathbf{A}$ is full rank so that the pseudoinverse satisfies $\mathbf{A}^\dagger = \mathbf{A}^T(\mathbf{A A}^T)^{-1}$. In your case $\mathbf{A} = \mathbf{1}^T$ so $\mathbf{A}^\dagger = n^{-1}\mathbf{1}$.

Answer (score 5):

You can always generate points uniformly on an n-sphere by sampling n+1 independent gaussians and then normalizing the resulting vector. So you ought to be able to do this by choosing n independent gaussians, projecting orthogonally to the plane, and then normalizing the vector.

Comment: Of course, you should do it w.r.t. a linear subspace if you want the normalization to preserve the subspace.

Comment: How would you normalize w.r.t a linear subspace ? I think here lies the point I am missing.

Comment: You normalize after you project, and the normalized vector stays parallel to the subspace.

Comment: I understood the principle but how to apply it (in my case) ? + another question comes to my mind, how do you manage the radius then ?

Comment: (1) Generate a rotationally symmetric Gaussian distribution. (2) Project to the hyperplane through the origin parallel to your hyperplane. (3) Normalize to get a uniform distribution on a sphere in the hyperplane. (4) Translate back to your hyperplane. Which step is the problem? And if you need a sphere of a different radius you rescale in step (3).

Comment: wouldn't this give you points inside the sphere instead of on the surface of the sphere ? Meaning if you refer to the graph I posted in 3D the result would be a disc.

Comment: No, that's not how normalization works.

Comment: Ok, let's think about it in $\mathbb{R}^3$. 
You sample m observations of 3 independent gaussians $(a_1,a_2,a_3)$ which you project orthogonally to the plane x+y+z = 1.
So now you get a series of m points on your plane.
You normalize using $\frac{a_i}{\sqrt{a_1^2+a_2^2+a_3^2}}$ with the projected coordinates.
Then you will get a semi-sphere intersecting your plane not a parallel circle.
If I misunderstood, the solution might be to normalize "in 2D" ie on the plane using only 2 coordinates and a basis of the plane but I do not see what general formula to use if we leave $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: Problem solved. See my answer below.

Comment: That formula is incorrect. You are normalizing first and then projecting. Instead, you should project first and then normalize the new coordinates. Do not divide by the length of the old, unprojected coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

See [Efficiently sampling points uniformly from the surface of an n-sphere](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/24688/efficiently-sampling-points-uniformly-from-the-surface-of-an-n-sphere) (I have voted to close this question as an exact duplicate of the above, btw)

Comment: My problem is not about generating points on a n-sphere. The algorithm in the question you posted is the same as the one I exposed (that's what I meant by "this algorithm allows you to generate points on a n-sphere too"). The problem is more about "rotating" and "translating" a generated sphere to fit on/in the hyperplane.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just find an orthogonal basis for your simplex, generate random points for a (n-2) sphere in cartesian coordinates, and then change basis (and translate)?

Comment: it seems difficult to write an algorithm that computes an orthogonal basis of the simplex (and change basis) for any dimension.

Comment: Why? The hyperplane is parallel to $x_1+x_2+...+x_n = 0 $. So if your sphere is on that plane, a translation will put it on the plane that you want, no?

Comment: Then you need to rotate your generated sphere to fit on the plane $x_1+x_2+...+x_n=0$, and how would you do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok sorry, I have been not doing geometry for too long !

I found the solution I wanted with the following algorithm which is I think not an exact replica of what Jason and Douglas were proposing but it seems to work :

(for 1 point - just sample m observations if you need more points)

1) Sample 1 observation of n independent gaussians $(a_1,a_2,...,a_n)$
You get a point $X= (x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$

2) Project it orthogonally to the hyperplane (in my case $x_1+x_2+...+x_n=1$) to get the projection $Y=(y_1,y_2,...,y_n)$

3) Normalize $Y$ w.r.t. the projection of the origin.

In my case the projection of the origin is $(1/n, 1/n, ..., 1/n)$

So to normalize I used :  $ \displaystyle \frac{Y}{\sqrt{(y_1-1/n)^2 + (y_2-1/n)^2+...+(y_n-1/n)^2}}$

4) Project the normalization one last time orthognally to your hyperplane to get a point on the surface of the unit (n-2)-sphere centered in $(1/n,...,1/n)$

If you want a radius $R$ and a specific center $C$ on the hyperplane you just need to scale with $R$ and add $C$ in 3).

Any comments on that method ?
In 3D, when I normalize in 3) I don't get a parallel circle as mention above by Douglas but a sort of cylinder which projected give me the circle. Any explanation ?

Thanks a lot for your help anyway.